# How do i use EF.CompileQuery in foreach loop (EF Core 3)?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have one class and one view model class.

UserClass contains about 30,000 records

```
[Key]
public int UserId { get; set; }

public string UserName { get; set; }

public string Email { get; set; }

public string Password { get; set; }

public string ActiveCode { get; set; }

public bool IsActive { get; set; }

public string UserAvatar { get; set; }

public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

public bool IsDelete { get; set; } = false;
```

and my viewmodel class contain

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
```

I want to run my query like this

```
var list=   EF.CompileQuery((TopLearnContext db) =>
                                 db.Users.Select(x=>new InformationUserViewModel()
                                 {
                                     Email = x.Email,
                                     UserName = x.UserName,
                                     RegisterDate = x.RegisterDate
                                 }));
                                 
                                 
         foreach (var item in list)
         {
             
         }
```

but got this error at run time:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Func<TopLearnContext, IEnumerable<InformationUserViewModel>>' because 'Func<TopLearnContext, IEnumerable<InformationUserViewModel>>' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

My question is, how can I do foreach loop in EF.CompileQuery?

As I know EF.CompileQuery improves performance and because of that I want to know how can I use it in foreach.

Comment: Don't use compile query, simple `db.Users.Select` will do work in enough performant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CompiledQuery` doesn't have anything to loop over. If you want the results from the query, it has to be executed first:

```
var toLoop = list.Invoke(context, ...)
```

Which will be an `IQueryable` which can be looped over.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply I try it and it works
but it takes times as like as this method

```
var list = db.Users.Select(x=>new InformationUserViewModel()
                                 {
                                     Email = x.Email,
                                     UserName = x.UserName,
                                     RegisterDate = x.RegisterDate
                                 }).toList();
```

shouldn`t EF.CompileQuery must have much faster compile time?